# react.js & tailwind.css project not deploying to heroku properly

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, web-deployment, tailwind-css

I have a create-react-app that I have successfully gotten up and running on my localhost, with all of the features of tailwind.css available for me to integrate with my JSX. It compiles fine and I used this tutorial to accomplish this: https://codingthesmartway.com/using-tailwind-css-with-react/.

An example of an error, commas representing new console log lines, is: npm ERR! react-tailwindcss@0.1.0 build:css: `postcss src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/main.css`, npm ERR! spawn ENOENT, npm ERR!, npm ERR! Failed at the react-tailwindcss@0.1.0 build:css script. I used heroku logs --tail to get this information. I am at a loss as to how to fix this issue. This is the app: https://peaceful-island-18911.herokuapp.com/. It should look like (and does on my localhost) the end result of the tutorial mentioned. I know there has to be a way to get a react w/ tailwindcss app deployed to heroku and function as it does on localhost. I have done it before using the more common css framework bootstrap.

Below is my package.json file with my scripts and dependencies. I followed the tutorial I mentioned above for my file architecture. I am a newer dev so please go easy on me but any help or guidance in solving this issue will be greatly appreciated. I really hope this is a simple fix beginner mistake! Thank you.

```
{
  "name": "react-tailwindcss",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build:css && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:css": "postcss src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/main.css",
    "prebuild": "npm run build:css",
    "prestart": "npm run build:css"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.6.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: so I haven't used heroku in a while, but when heroku deploys I believe it strips everything from the devDependencies. making all those devDependencies into actual dependencies instead of dev ones might do the trick

Comment: npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-tailwindcss@0.1.0 prestart: `npm run build:css`
npm ERR! Exit status 1,
npm ERR!,
npm ERR! Failed at the react-tailwindcss@0.1.0 prestart script. is the first error I got after trying that. I did noticing during build it does say pruning dev dependencies at one point so that would make sense. Unfortunately switching them to being regular dependencies did not seem to change much about what I see when I visit the deployed version. Thank you for your answer and any other idea you might think of. Would AWS be better for any reason?

Comment: Update: I solved the issue. Heroku is trash I went with Netlify instead which checks to make sure a build is run properly for you and checks and does it for you if it isn't set up.